# How to find private VPN server located in USA?

Tags: vpn, web

I am not asking for any recommendation! Please don't vote for closing the question. I am asking about how to properly search for them!

Now, I tried to find a private VPN server, but all services I found offer public VPNs. As a result, I pay for their service and get banned on a specific web sites in a couple of days. So obviously all those public VPNs are blacklisted on all major websites.

I am now asking a way to find private whitelisted VPNs. What terms should I search for? I already spent too much time and money and start to think that there is not such VPN.

Comment: A question on how to google search isn't on topic.  Your not going to find a private VPN for free; the VPN services I have used which are paid were all private

Comment: I am not searching for free but paid service. But paid with private undetected vpns.

Comment: Still off topic we can't help you locate these services beyond telling you the best way is to run your own VPN server through your own dedecated server hosted some where of your choice

Comment: Other than this being off topic, I think you have some misunderstanding on how VPNs work. If you pay for a service it can still be blocked through various means by the destination. The best suggestion here would be to host your own.

Answer (score 1):

Your definitions of *public* and *private* are very arbitrary.
If you want to use VPN service that is not abused by others, run your own. There are plenty of resources and instructions online that tell you how to run one on Amazon EC2 or other services.

Comment: What are the costs of such approach?

Comment: However much it cost to run an appropriate sized server on the hosting platform of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

It depend on  you that what you consider to find the private whitelisted VPNs. Searching VPN is not a big thing but there are not a single vpn provider in market so you can't find the best one because everyone can't satisfied with every vpn because of different issue but it does not mean that you will face the same problems with this VPN and you should know that there is lots of competition so its very easily to create negative perception ... Go with positive thinking and read the reviews I'd suggest to visit bestvpnservice.com and read the reviews of different vpn providers hope it will help you..